# Error in updating form values in mongoDB using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, put

Post Delete options are working fine but the put is not working it updates successfully but with ***function String() { [native code] }*** values.

controller.ts

```
router.put('/:id', (req,res)=> {
    if (!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id)) {
        return res.status(400).send('No record with the given Id ${req.params.id}');
    }

    var emp = {
        email: String,
        name : String ,
        position :  String ,
        office : String,
        // salary : Number
    };

    Employee.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $set : emp },(err,docs) => {
        if (!err) {
            res.send(docs);
        } else {
            console.log('Error in Updating the Employee details' + JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2))
        }
    });
});
```

model.ts

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Employee = mongoose.model('Employee',{
    name : String ,
    position :  String ,
    office : String,
    salary : Number,
    email : String,
})

module.exports = { Employee }
```

Comment: Hi, I know this is a very late answer, but did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read from your req.body, and use those values to create employee body.

```
router.put("/:id", (req, res) => {
  if (!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id)) {
    return res.status(400).send(`Not a valid id ${req.params.id}`);
  }

  const { email, name, position, office, salary } = req.body;

  var emp = { email, name, position, office, salary };

  Employee.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    { $set: emp },
    { new: true },
    (err, doc) => {
      if (!err) {
        if (doc) {
          res.send(doc);
        } else {
          res.status(400).send("Not found");
        }
      } else {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Let's say you have this employee document.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e01d6d21151ad62600b1ba6"),
    "name" : "Employee 1",
    "position" : "Web developer",
    "office" : "Software",
    "salary" : 1111,
    "email" : "emp1@microsoft.com",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

If we want to update position and salary, we can use this request.body:

```
{
    "name": "Employee 1",
    "position": "Senior Web developer",
    "office": "Software",
    "salary": 2222,
    "email": "emp1@microsoft.com"
}
```

When you send a PUT request to your route  (`.../5e01d6d21151ad62600b1ba6`) with this body, the result will be like this:

```
{
    "_id": "5e01d6d21151ad62600b1ba6",
    "name": "Employee 1",
    "position": "Senior Web developer",
    "office": "Software",
    "salary": 2222,
    "email": "emp1@microsoft.com",
    "__v": 0
}
```